# Easy examples of the Arzela-Ascoli Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, compactness, examples-counterexamples

> Let $X$ be a compact metric space. $M \subseteq C(X)$ is relatively compact if and only if $M$ (i.e. its elements) is equicontinuous and uniformly bounded.

I've been told that this theorem gives me a characterization of the relatively compact subsets of $M$. Could somebody provide some (easy) examples for this? I do understand the implication, but I fail to see where I can use this in an easy and obvious way. I tried Wikipedia, but those examples seem complicated.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're right that it seems to be harder to find super easy applications of Arzela-Ascoli then, say, the contraction mapping fixed point theorem. However, major theorems in analysis like the Peano existence theorem, the Riemann mapping theorem, Picard's theorems, and Koebe's theorem follow from the Arzela-Ascoli theorem plus a bit more work. So you can rest assured that it is very powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Try $X = [0,1]$, $M$ the set of differentiable functions $f$ on $X$ such that $|f(x)| \le 1$ and $|f'|(x) \le 1$ everywhere.